# R services for SQL and T-SQL, memory issues when running multiple stored procedures

Tags: r, sql-server, azure

We are running R services for SQL on an Azure VM to create a web interface to a modeling algorithm. We are using T-SQL to call a very complicated and memory intensive R script. It runs fine when we submit a single job but we get a memory allocation error when we submit another job before the 1st has finished. Eventually we will need to queue hundreds of jobs that will run over many hours. We assume that it is initiating two R processes which use up the resources. What is the best way to force it to run the R jobs sequentially rather than simultaneously? We have looked at updating the resource pool to MAX_PROCESSES = 0, with no success (we have already adjusted memory resources in this way) . We are considering using the Azure Service Bus Queue but we are hoping there might be simpler options. We would appreciate any advice on how others have dealt with this sort of issue. 
Thanks 10^6.

Comment: make them into seperate store procs and you can run them sequentially via Sql server job agent.

Comment: keep in mind something this memory intensive will blow up your budget on Azure VM :) . It happened to the data science team at my last project. Had to do things on prem .

Comment: We are using the job agent. It took our team very little time to set up and it works great. Thanks!